# Romex into Carlon 5070 phenolic resin boxes. Knockouts?

Tags: electrical

For various reasons I'd like to use the Carlon 5070 phenolic resin boxes for my switches, with romex. The knockouts look weird: rectangle holes, two on each of the four edges in back. How do they work? Is it code to use those with no clamps? I'm in Hawaii.

Answer (score 1):

The type of knockout you describe on a plastic box is an integral NM clamp -- it's Code to use these on NM cable (but only on NM cable -- if you want to hook up conduit to it, you'll need to drill your own knockout.)

Comment: Technically, altering the manufactured assembly of the box with drill holes is not the best advice.

Comment: It is totally legal and common practice to modify boxes as long as listed fittings are used.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the images of that box they are just like phenolic nail-on boxes.

Single gang non-metallic boxes do not require cable clamps or connectors, but do require that the cable be secured (stapled) within 8" of the box as opposed to 12" for other boxes.

I know you did not ask about it, but a box like that is not meant for conduit.

Comment: That's very helpful Speedy Petey and ThrePhaseEel. Someone told me use a screwdriver to pry up and break the outside side of the box where those rectangular slots are, then use it again to pry and break the inside sidewalls of the box where the slots are. Anyone done that?